# Add timing delay to AutoFit Macro on Open

Tags: ms-word, word-2010

Here is the Macro that I am running on the `Document_Open` in Word 2010

```
Sub Document_Open()
Dim t As Table
For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
t.AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitContent
Next t
End Sub
```

This will auto-fit all tables to the contents of the window.
The issue comes in that there is another command running on the document that populates the tables and `Document_Open` runs it before the tables are populated and thus is not automating what I need.

I would like to add a 15 second delay into this macro to allow all tables to be populated prior to running the auto-fit.

Comment: Then don't do it in `Document_Open`. Write a different macro that executes this code, and call that macro from the end of the code that populates the tables.

Comment: That is a great idea.  However, I do not have access to the code that populates the tables.  It is hidden through the EMR.

Comment: The point is that you're not going to be able to delay `Document_Open`, because it's specifically designed to execute when the document is opened (the exact reason it has the name that it does). You can't say *run this code in the Document_Open sub, but not when the document is opened but 15 seconds later*. You need another means of doing so. If you can't alter the data load, then make the macro manually run by a hotkey or button after the data is loaded.

Comment: I like the idea of running the Macro off of a hotkey and beleive that I could figure that out with some research.  Any chance that I could create a dialog pop up box that once clicked could perform the Macro I wrote?  I could just direct staff to hold on clicking until the tables are loaded.